# Ajax request not returning an HttpResponse

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django

I'm coding a django web app with only one page. This page contains a form with some inputs. When I click on the submit button, I make an ajax call to a function in python. I want to get back some data from this function.

**HTML file:**

```
<form id="strategy" method="post" class="edit_user">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="sel-schedule">
    <label>Label: </label>
    <input id="start_time" type="time" name="start_time" value="09:30" required>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="inactive boton-lanzar">Launch</button>
</form>
```

**JS file**:

```
$('#strategy').on('submit', function(event){
    var start_time = document.getElementsByName("start_time")[0].value;
    var url = '/method_calculation/';
    $.ajax(url, {
        data: {
            'start_time': start_time,
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
          console.log("new")
        }
    })
});
```

**Urls file:**

```
urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('', home, name='home'),
path('method_calculation/', method_calculation, name="method_calculation"),
]
```

**Views file:**

```
def home(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render(request, 'index.html')
    else:
        return HttpResponse("OK")


def method_calculation(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':

        start_time_hour = int(request.POST.get('start_time')[0:2])
        start_time_minute = int(request.POST.get('start_time')[3:5])
        data_comparison = caculate_summit(start_time_hour, start_time_minute)

        args = {data_comparison}
        return JsonResponse(args)
```

I'm a bit confused.

First, I don't want the page to reload but if I take out the return HttpResponse it says that it needs it.

Second, with the current files I get the following error:

```
The view myapp.views.method_calculation didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
```

What am I missing?

Many thanks

Comment: Your are making a `GET` request, so the method is returning `None`, hence the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I am doing when I am doing a post request in Ajax on my Django Projects.
According, django documentation(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/csrf/), the best way to get csrf token is using this function:

```
function getCookie(name) {
    var cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
        var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
            // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}

function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
    // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
    return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
}
```

I built then an ajax post function with this:

```
function postAjaxJson(url, data, is_csrf, callback) {
    if (is_csrf) {
        var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
        $.ajaxSetup({
            beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
                if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
                }
            }
        });
    }
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        success: function(response) {
            callback(response);
        },
        error: function () {
            console.error("Erreur réseau avec l'url" + url);
        }
    })
}
```

I usually send my datas in JSON.
And, in your view, you will find the data from your ajax post in **request.body**, not in request.POST:

```
import json
def method_calculation(request):
    if request.body:

        ...
        # if json data = json.loads(request.body)
        ...
        return JsonResponse(args)
```

I hope this will help you to resolve your problem!

Answer (score 1):

Your AJAX call is making a GET request, and the view function does not handle this case. As a result it returns `None`, and hence the error.

You thus need to specify the request type in the `$.ajax` call:

```
$.ajax(url, {
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        start_time: start_time,
        csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
      console.log("new")
    }
})
```

Based on your comment, you also need to specify the CSRF token (given the JavaScript is rendered with a template, the above should work).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I changed it and now I receive a 403 error, I'll look for it before opening a new post.

Comment: @AlbertoCarmona: does your view performs authentication? or a CSRF token?

Comment: Yes a CSRF token